# how to set default value of first date of current month and next month in liquibase?

Tags: postgresql, spring-boot, liquibase

I am able to create partition using below liquibase yaml.

Is there a way by which I can dynamically pass date range in liquibase? In liquibase , we can pass current timestamp via property tag of liquibase but how to pass first date of current month and first date of next month via liquibase property or changelog parameter.

```
databaseChangeLog:
  - property:
      dbms: postgresql
      name: now
      value:  CURRENT_DATE
    - changeSet:
          id: 1
          author: roran
          changes:
            - createTable:
                tableName: account_balance
                columns:
                  - column:
                      name: id
                      type: bigint
                      autoIncrement: true
                      constraints:
                        primaryKey: true
                  - column:
                      name: account_id
                      type: bigint
                      constraints:
                        nullable: false
                  - column:
                      name: balance_date
                      type: date
                      constraints:
                        primaryKey: true
                  - column:
                      name: create_date
                      type: timestamptz
                  - column:
                      name: created_by
                      type: varchar(100)
                  - column:
                      name: update_date
                      type: timestamptz
                  - column:
                      name: updated_by
                      type: varchar(100)
            - modifySql:
                applyToRollback: false
                dbms: postgresql
                append:
                  value: PARTITION BY RANGE (balance_date); CREATE TABLE public.account_balance_p0 PARTITION OF
                  account_balance FOR VALUES FROM ('2020-08-01 00:00:00') TO ('2020-10-01 00:00:00');
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are trying to make the first and last date parameterized, as you mentioned you could use [Liquibiase Changelog Substitution](https://docs.liquibase.com/concepts/basic/changelog-parameters.html)
and make this following change to your changeset:

```
        - modifySql:
            applyToRollback: false
            dbms: postgresql
            append:
              value: PARTITION BY RANGE (balance_date); CREATE TABLE public.account_balance_p0 PARTITION OF
              account_balance FOR VALUES FROM ('${start.date}') TO ('${end.date}');
```

You could call Liquibase in the following way to pass the dates in:

```
liquibase -Dstart.date=<property.value> -Dend.date=<property.value> update
```

HTH,

Ronak

Comment: I am looking for a way where I dont need to pass value via code or properties file but liquibase should calculate dynamically. I guess that's not possible.

I thought if now() can get current timestamp then DATE_TRUNC('MONTH',NOW() + INTERVAL '1 MONTH') should get me next month timestamp.

Something like this I wanted via liquibase

Comment: That's a cool idea user2800089.  Liquibase does not do that currently but we are community driven so if you were up for hacking: Liquibase is having a hackathon and accepting either the idea (thru github issues) or actually modifications (thru github PRs) on the following repo: https://github.com/liquibase/liquibase